# PackageReference path is not resolved with dotnet build

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have the following project/target I want to run with **dotnet build** in our build pipeline.
The problem is that I need to find the location of the InnoSetup tools path underneath the nuget repository folder. `PackageReference` allows to resolve the location by using the `GeneratePathProperty`, but when I execute the targets-file below, the path is not resolved.

Is there any explanation why this doesn't work?

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Tools.InnoSetup" Version="6.2.2" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="TakeAction" AfterTargets="Build">
      <Exec Command="$(PkgTools_InnoSetup)\tools\ISCC.exe" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

when using

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Tools.InnoSetup" Version="6.2.2" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="TakeAction" AfterTargets="build">
      <Exec Command="$(PkgTools_InnoSetup)\tools\ISCC.exe" />
    </Target>   
</Project>
```

seems to work with the whole Sdk required. So I need to find the imports which are required to setup the NuGet properties.

Comment: Can you share the error message? [`GeneratePathProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty) is "available with NuGet 5.0 or above and with Visual Studio 2019 16.0 or above." You can check the version of `nuget` in the `dotnet` tool with `dotnet nuget --version`. You can check that your "TakeAction" target is run and check the value of the `$(PkgTools_InnoSetup)` property by adding a `Message` task inside your target. e.g. `<Message text="PkgTools_InnoSetup = $(PkgTools_InnoSetup)" Importance="high" />`.

Comment: I'm using nuget version: 6.4.0.117. The output path  is empty: PkgTools_InnoSetup =.

Comment: Seems like it should be working but it seems like the property is not being defined. You could try running the build with `-v:diag` (`-verbosity:diagnostic`) and see if the diagnostic output shows that the property is being defined or not. You could also try the `-pp` (`-preprocess`) switch to output a version of the project after all imports have been performed. Search for `GeneratePathProperty` in the preprocess output to see if you can pick up on when and how the path property is defined.

Comment: I was able to make some progress see above
seems to work, when including the whole Sdk. I will dig a bit deeper what is required to get the Nuget properties without having to set the whole NET.Sdk.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`?

Comment: Not really. The problem is that if I set the Sdk a target framework is required. If it works as above its OK for me, I just wanted to optimize it a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255210/discussion-between-jonathan-dodds-and-msedi).